# Running docker commands as a build step in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker

I am running some docker commands as a post build step in Jenkins, and it is failing. My job is running on a slave node, and when I go to the slave host and execute the docker commands directly, everything works. Just as a simple test, I use the following as a post-build step:

```
docker ps
```

The output in the console is this:

- docker ps
  Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

The only user on this machine is the one that is building, and it is set to the docker group. What might be different about the environment of the build itself, and when I ssh into the node host that could cause this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Check whether the environment variable $DOCKER_HOST is set or not.

Comment: $DOCKER_HOST is not defined either on the host when connected through ssh, or when the job is being run through Jenkins. Since the host is Ubuntu 14.04 and the daemon is running natively, I would assume no need for this environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that Jenkins slave processes are long-running, and not spun up for each job.  I had to restart the slave node in order for the docker group added to the jenkins user to take effect. Case Closed :D

Comment: Just for reference a jenkins-slave service restart sorted this for me as well, e.g. on CentOS: `systemctl restart jenkins-slave`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they are both using the same user?
You probably have to add the user jenkins is running with to the docker group.

Comment: I double checked that the user is the same, at least as reported by the $USER environment variable. This thing really has me stumped.

Comment: Is the GID of your docker group inside your container the same as the GID of your dockergroup on your host?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can run Docker if everything is well setup. The user configuration can be done, the Jenkins user able to run docker, but 
still failling with `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

I just needed to execute the following in a build

`+ id
uid=987(jenkins) gid=982(jenkins) groups=982(jenkins)`

to see the difference with the bash user

`-bash-4.2$ id
uid=987(jenkins) gid=982(jenkins) groups=982(jenkins),981(docker)`

To see that docker was missing. Just needed to restart Jenkins !!